# Dynamically replace value in multidimensional array with another value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in PHP and try to dynamically replace values with another value in that array.

Here's an example:

```
$data =
array(356) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "001"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "14.04.2018 14:00:00"
    [2]=>
    string(39) "mJA"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "JSG Handball"
    [4]=>
    string(13) "TSG Frankfurt"
    [5]=>
    string(52) "1410601539 Ground 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "001"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "14.04.2018 14:00:00"
    [2]=>
    string(48) "wJB"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "SC Berlin"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "JSG Handball"
    [5]=>
    string(44) "1410601105 Ground 2"
  }
...
}
```

What I need to achieve is, I want to search the entire array and replace any finding of the string "JSG Handball" with the string in the Array key [x][2]. So, in my example "JSG Handball" would be replaced by "mJA" and "JSG Handball" would be replaced by "wJB" in the second finding.

What I achieved so far (thanks to that wonderful people here) is a static replacement with array_walk_recursive, but I can't get any further.

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$data) {      
    if($data == "JSG Handball") {
         $data = "Whatever";
    }
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated ;)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) will give you the value and the key for every item but not the current array those key and value are in.

What you could do is loop your array using 2 times a `foreach` and use `&` to pass by reference to update the original array.

```
$data = [
    [
        "001",
        "14.04.2018 14:00:00",
        "mJA",
        "JSG Handball",
        "TSG Frankfurt",
        "1410601539 Ground 1",
    ],
    [
        "001",
        "14.04.2018 14:00:00",
        "wJB",
        "SC Berlin",
        "JSG Handball",
        "1410601105 Ground 2"
    ]
];

foreach ($data as &$d) {
    foreach ($d as &$item) {
        if ($item === "JSG Handball" && isset($d[2])) {
            $item = $d[2];
        }
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/mCRTN)